# Smooth out Density Plot Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, density-plot

I am importing a three column table into Mathematica and using it to make a density plot. However unless you have a very large amount of data in small increments the density plot looks disjointed and obviously not continuous.

is there a way or a function to smooth out my plots?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the `InterpolationOrder` option. Below is the example from the documentation which shows how it works even for a 6x6 data grid

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
Table[ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> o, 
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"], {o, {0, 1, 2, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beat you by 5 seconds :)

Comment: @belisarius What the heck.. wait, let me downvote your answer for non-existing code formatting in the first version ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `InterpolationOrder`:

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}];
GraphicsRow@{ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3], 
             ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> None]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]